# How to set max seconds in an ionic datetime component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am using ionic 5 and have a ionic datetime picker that allows users to select hours minutes and seconds. However, I need to be able to set the maximum time so that a user cannot select a time that is greater. I set the max property of the datetime component and it seems to work for hours and minutes but ignores the seconds. Does anyone have a clue?

[Sample code in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-zwowdf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it seems to be a bug in Ionic source code :(

When taking a look at **[this line of code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/master/core/src/components/datetime/datetime.tsx#L473)** it can be seen that the `validateColumns()` method validates the year, the month, the day, the hour, and the minute **but not the seconds**:

```
  private validateColumns(columns: PickerColumn[]) {
    const today = new Date();
    const minCompareVal = dateDataSortValue(this.datetimeMin);
    const maxCompareVal = dateDataSortValue(this.datetimeMax);
    const yearCol = columns.find(c => c.name === 'year');

    let selectedYear: number = today.getFullYear();
    if (yearCol) {
      // default to the first value if the current year doesn't exist in the options
      if (!yearCol.options.find(col => col.value === today.getFullYear())) {
        selectedYear = yearCol.options[0].value;
      }

      const selectedIndex = yearCol.selectedIndex;
      if (selectedIndex !== undefined) {
        const yearOpt = yearCol.options[selectedIndex] as PickerColumnOption | undefined;
        if (yearOpt) {
          // they have a selected year value
          selectedYear = yearOpt.value;
        }
      }
    }

    const selectedMonth = this.validateColumn(columns,
      'month', 1,
      minCompareVal, maxCompareVal,
      [selectedYear, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [selectedYear, 12, 31, 23, 59]
    );

    const numDaysInMonth = daysInMonth(selectedMonth, selectedYear);
    const selectedDay = this.validateColumn(columns,
      'day', 2,
      minCompareVal, maxCompareVal,
      [selectedYear, selectedMonth, 0, 0, 0],
      [selectedYear, selectedMonth, numDaysInMonth, 23, 59]
    );

    const selectedHour = this.validateColumn(columns,
      'hour', 3,
      minCompareVal, maxCompareVal,
      [selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay, 0, 0],
      [selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay, 23, 59]
    );

    this.validateColumn(columns,
      'minute', 4,
      minCompareVal, maxCompareVal,
      [selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay, selectedHour, 0],
      [selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay, selectedHour, 59]
    );

    return columns;
  }
```

Maybe the issue is somewhere else and not in that specific line but anyway there's a Github issue with a list of a lot of bugs related to the `ion-datetime` component (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/16630) so I'd recommend you to **[create a new issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/new/choose)** with your stackblitz demo and add a comment to include this bug in that list.

You could also **[submit a PR](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md)** as well if you want :)

I couldn't find any workarounds since we can't listen to the columns change for now, so I guess the only solution until this issue is fixed would be to validate the seconds after the user clicks on done and show an error message if it's bigger than the max (I know, it's far from ideal unfortunately).